# Rails 4: Strong parameters + nested attributes + multiple select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I have a model called `TaxCategory`, that `has_many :tax_rates` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tax_rates, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true`.

`TaxRates` itself is a model, which, amongst other things, `has_and_belongs_to_many :countries`.

These relations work fine, and I am able to add and remove countries through the console.

However, I have a form for TaxCategory that contains `fields_for :tax_rates do |g|`.

Inside here, I have a

```
g.select :country_ids, Country.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, {multiple: true}, {}
```

It submits to the `tax_categories` controller, which uses the following code to update the `TaxCategory`:

```
class TaxCategoriesController
  before_action :set_tax_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 ...*snip*...

  def update
     respond_to do |format|
      if @tax_category.update(tax_category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [:dashboard,  @tax_category], notice: 'Tax Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tax_category }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @tax_category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    private

  def set_tax_category
    @tax_category = TaxCategory.find(params[:id])
  end

  def tax_category_params
    params.require(:tax_category).permit(:name, tax_rates_attributes:[:id, :rate,{country_ids: []}, :_destroy])
  end


end
```

However, this does **not** work; When submitting the form, only the very first Country is saved, and the Rails command line shows the `Unpermitted parameter: country_ids` message.

I think this is a problem that is caused by the `params.permit`, but I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

What is going wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I think I found the problem. Your sample params say `country_ids: 1`, in which it should instead be `country_ids: [1]` because it should have been an array / multiple values.

Update the following into:

```
g.select :country_ids, Country.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, {}, {multiple: true}
```

<del>Unpermitted Params error feels like it is most likely `tax_category_params` is the problem. Can you try this

    def tax_category_params
      params.require(:tax_category).permit(:name, tax_rates_attributes: [:id, :rate, country_ids: [], :_destroy])
    end</del>

Comment: That turns out to be invalid Ruby syntax, as the interpreter has trouble figuring out how to wrap it up as a hash by itself (Which I believe has to do with [named parameters](http://brainspec.com/blog/2012/10/08/keyword-arguments-ruby-2-0/). Placing it at the end, like so: `params.require(:tax_category).permit(:name, tax_rates_attributes:[:id, :rate, :_destroy, country_ids: []])` does not produce the syntax error, but still has the exact same result as above, e.g. `Unpermitted parameter: country_ids`

Comment: Hmm. can you `puts params` inside update action? I am curious to see the actual params of the request. The `tax_category_params` looks ok to me.

Comment: The params that are sent to the request are: `{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"424242VHWTNtNTDzPhV9U1aV+t1d2VBx9+heakYGSyozK+MkYvCPc3JJZIB+zSXn2vsqucZQ/P2J8F8ale2Yw==", "tax_category"=>{"name"=>"General", "tax_rates_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"rate"=>"21.0", "country_ids"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"rate"=>"10.0", "country_ids"=>"2,3,4", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"3"}}}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"1"}`, which looks fine to me.

Comment: Indeed. It seems to have been caused by my Form Builder, which returns `country_ids: "1,2,3,4,5"` instead of `country_ids: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`. Thank you!